# Sort in LINQ with dynamic/custom sort

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

here's my scenario.. I need to sort a list of objects by a variety of fields, what I have now is...

```
comparisons.OrderBy(c => c.FlexDifference)
            .ThenBy(c => c.ShaftDensityDifference)
            .ThenBy(c => c.TorqueDifference)
            .ThenBy(c => c.LaunchDifference);
```

However, now I need to sort by another field in the middle, material, which is currently just a string value being used as an enum (and unfortunately will probably stay this way). Let's say this string can be `matOne`, `matTwo`, or `matThree`, the sort order of these strings is dynamic (e.g., it might be `matTwo`, then `matOne`, then `matThree`) between three sorting scenarios. I'm not sure how to approach this - I've been playing with something like...

```
var materialSortType = GetMaterialSortType();
comparisons.OrderBy(c => c.FlexDifference)
            .ThenBy(c => c.ShaftDensityDifference)
            .ThenBy(c => MaterialComparator(c.Material, materialSortType))
            .ThenBy(c => c.TorqueDifference)
            .ThenBy(c => c.LaunchDifference);
```

What is the best way to go about this type of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload of the .ThenBy method that receives the keySelector and the Comparer. In your example that would be:

```
var materialComparer = GetMaterialComparer();
comparisons.OrderBy(c => c.FlexDifference)
        .ThenBy(c => c.ShaftDensityDifference)
        .ThenBy(c => c.Material, materialComparer))
        .ThenBy(c => c.TorqueDifference)
        .ThenBy(c => c.LaunchDifference);
```

Where materialComparer should implement IComparer< String>.

Here is an example on how you could implement that:

```
Comparer<String> GetMaterialComparer()
{
   if(condition1...)
      return new materialComparer1();
   if(condition2...)
      return new materialComparer2();
   etc...
}

class materialComparer1 : materialComparer
{
    static Dictionary<String, int> specificOrder = new Dictionary<String, int>
                {
                    {"matOne", 2},
                    {"matTwo", 1},
                    {"matThree", 3}
                };

    protected override Dictionary<string, int> order { get { return specificOrder; } }
}

abstract class materialComparer : Comparer<String>
{            
    protected abstract Dictionary<String, int> order{get;}
    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return order[x].CompareTo(order[y]);
    }
}
```

materialComparer2 would be similar to materialComparer1 just defining a different order,

Hope this helps you,

Best Regards